# Subcaption not in center of minipage

Tags: minipage, subcaption

I want to have a label to my minipage of just the "a)" and when I do this it is not in the center of my image. This is not a failure of subcaption but a characteristic of my image of too much white space on one side so it looks like this. More precicely I want to move the subcaption to one side a little bit. Is this possible somehow? I want to use the `minipage` and `subcaption` package if possible.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.99\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{some image}
   \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}
 \label{some label}
 \caption{some caption}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a custom caption format with the command `\DeclareCaptionFormat` and apply this to the subcaption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelformat=brace]{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\hspace*{1cm}#1}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.99\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{some image}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}
  \label{some label}
  \caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I've used a horizontal space of `1cm` before the label, which you should change to your preference. The format can be specified with `#1` where the label should appear, `#2` where the label separator should appear, and `#3` for were he caption text should appear. Since you only seemed to need the label, I didn't add the last two, meaning that no caption text will show up if you provide one, then you should use`\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\hspace*{1cm}#1#2#3}` instead.

If you just want to use the custom format on selected subcaptions, place the `\captionsetup` within the environment.

Also, the package option `labelformat=brace` for the `subcaption` package is to ensure that the caption label is typeset as `a)` rather than the default `(a)`.